# Tracking the user's source; Google analytics

Tags: google-analytics

Is there a way to track the multiple sources users might be using to visit a page.
Scenario:  I have one Destination URL which can be visited by multiple websites, what is the way to decipher that how much traffic (or more particularly which user) came from which of the source pages.

Thanks in advance!! :)

Answer (score 0):

[Read here](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/6099206?hl=en) about source/medium

[or here](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1033867) about UTM